# what does "make check" do?

Tags: makefile

I wonder in the installation process of `configure`, `make`, `make check` and `make install`, what does `make check` do? Thanks!

Comment: Anything that is specified in Makefile for target `check`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it doesn't necessarily do anything.

If a Makefile has a target named check, then *make check* will "build" that target. It's typically a phony target, meaning that it is a make-scripted command rather than a file named "check" that gets created.

The gnu project advises that all gnu software should include a *make check* target that runs post-build tests in the build directory, so `make check` can be used frequently on packages distributed from the FSF. Other projects will sometimes follow this convention as well.

Answer (score 16):

According to the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Standard-Targets), it performs self tests on the program this makefile builds.

Comment: A better link would be to: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Standard-Targets

Answer (score 11):

`make check` is a command to a makefile. It does whatever the makefile defines it to do.

It sounds like a little background on makefiles would be good. [This](https://faculty.cs.byu.edu/~rodham/cs240/make-tutorial.html) is a tutorial that my school uses for a programming course. Here are some good quotes:

> `Make` can be used to automatically execute the many Linux commands that are needed to compile, link, and test a large C++ program. Since these commands will be executed hundreds of times during a program's development, automating these tasks is essential.

Comment: Link to tutorial is broken(

Answer (score 0):

The most common place that you will see this is when automake is used. Automake has features that make (no pun intended) it relatively simple to generate a series of test cases and produce a pretty summary of the results. For more info, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Tests.html):