# Shared lib installation

Tags: r

I am new to Ubuntu..

I am trying to install R in Ubuntu with shared lib options and I got some errors.
Here are the steps I followed and error I got while installation. Please help me/ correct me if I miss anything.

First I added cran links in sources.list file. I understand that, this will help me to download latest version of the R.

```
#Editing sources.list
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

#There are the lines added in sources.list file
deb http://cran.ms.unimelb.edu.au/bin/linux/ubuntu raring/
deb http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe

#To enable secure key
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9
gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -

#updating the ubuntu repositories 
sudo apt-get update

#building R dependents
sudo apt-get build-dep r-base
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

This actually installed R-.3.0.1

Again I downloaded a R-3.0.1.tar.gz and extracted then I tried enabling shared lib facilities. These are the steps I followed. when I check the make files, showing some errors. I am not quite sure what is the issue with configuration. please help me on the same

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar -xzf R-3.0.1.tar.gz
cd R-3.0.1
./configure --enable-R-shlib
make check
```

here are the error messages:

```
sivaji@VB:~/Downloads/R-3.0.1$ make check
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sivaji/Downloads/R-3.0.1/tests'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/sivaji/Downloads/R-3.0.1/tests'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sivaji/Downloads/R-3.0.1/tests/Examples'
/bin/bash: ../../bin/R: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [test-Examples-Base] Error 127
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sivaji/Downloads/R-3.0.1/tests/Examples'
make[2]: *** [test-Examples] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sivaji/Downloads/R-3.0.1/tests'
make[1]: *** [test-all-basics] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sivaji/Downloads/R-3.0.1/tests'
make: *** [check] Error 2
```

Please help on the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would assume the standard Ubuntu installation comes already with the enabled shared lib. Do you receive an error or why would you like to compile your own R? Could you run `ldd /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R` in the terminal and see if the shared object `libR.so` is loaded? If so, your installed R has the option already enabled.

Comment: yes this is showing libR.so file. means, it is installed correctly?

Comment: It seems like that... And the package you want to install is probably spelled `Rserve` and not Rserver as you wrote earlier in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

[`make check`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735473/what-does-make-check-do) checks that the program you just compiled works fine. You need to compile it first, e.g. with `make` (no arguments) or `make -j 8` (faster, if you have several cores). You will also need to install it, with `sudo make install`.

Comment: I tried make and then sudo make install and then tried checking make check. still the same errors showing. and one more point is I am trying to install Rserver package and it is saying not available

Comment: If you have the same error message, saying that the `R` executable was not found, it means that `make` failed to create it: there should be an earlier error message.

Comment: After I read few documents and help, I understand that it is doesn't required downloading again and configuring with shlib. It will install as shared lib when we download binaries. But need to check libR.so file is created or not.

    R CMD config --ldflags # this will return a location check to see whether the libR.so file exists in the location